# Issue with Calculating pro-rata value using 'bit' value for condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a need to retrieve invoices and calculating interest charge based on their due date & only when the due date < current date (i.e. overdue). I figured it would be far quicker to calculate the interest charge in my stored procedure that's retrieving the invoices, than charging the fee in the BI layer of the application - [this was my reference for that assumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479031/pros-cons-of-implementing-calculations-in-c-sharp-instead-of-sql).

My problem is that I cannot get a condition to work when the 'bit' value = 1. My SQL condition is below

```
DECLARE @dailydiscount decimal;
DECLARE @proRata bit = (SELECT [ProRataFee] from [tbl_FinanceFee] where [customerID] = @ID)

IF (@proRata = 1)
    SET @dailydiscount = @discountRate / @DaysInMonth;
else 
    SET @dailydiscount = 1
```

So my problem is that whenever `@proRata = 1`, `@dailydiscount=0` even though I can see it should be a decimal value. Weirdly, when `@proRata = 0`, `@dailydiscount=1` so the logic does work to some extent

I need this condition as some customers are charged an interest charge that is pro-rated and others are charged a fee that is a percentage of the overdue invoice irrespective of the days overdue.

PS I've even tried changing `@proRata`'s type to an int and the issue persisted.

The other variables (@discountRate & @DaysInMonth) work as expected and are of the types: decimal and int respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing dailydiscount to be type Decimal(4,2) for example. I think decimal by default is (18,0).

Comment: What a simple solution! Thank you, I knew it was this easy - I'd ended up using a CASE statement in the select and applying the logic there. I think this solution will make the SP much easier to read six months from now